# Angular performance ngFor of components or ngFor of html

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, ngfor

I have question, what is more performance way to show list:

- In one hand there use ngFor of components like: list-item ngFor="let item of list"
- In other hand use html instead of component like:  div ngFor....

What do you think?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO! What do you want to compare? please explain in detail. 
Your question is not clear

Comment: Thanks. I want to compare performance of showing n count of same component? or is it better to use direct html without component to iterate array?

Comment: It depends, how much generic component you are building. Since its ngFor which will take just milliseconds to execute. In my opinion if its just small peace of code then do it within HTML itself. If it has some additional functionality rather than iterating a values, then go for component. Otherwise it wont make much sense to execute all the lifecycle hooks of  a component just for iterating couple of items.

Comment: I need to iterate complex object, with additional components inside, with some actions there and checks in template. And i will have to show let say around 200 items with infinity scroll. Is it change Your decision above? Other question can You propose good tool to check performance of such operation?

Comment: Then go for component.

Comment: You can use Chrome lighthouse itself it can give you detail report

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the performance for yourself using [performance.measure()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure) between ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit. I would expect that writing out the html would be faster than ngFor by some tiny fraction of a millisecond, but that 'gain' is completely irrelevant and unnoticeable. For a real app, go with whatever makes your code more clear and easy to read.

Comment: This is good answer, but one of my coworkers has strong different opinion about that. He prefer to copy past and use ng-template instead of reuse component. And Also he think that using ngFor of html is better that use trackBy and onPush.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I misunderstood your original question and in fact what you are asking is to compare the performance difference between iterating over plain HTML vs iterating over a component and in which case this makes no difference because at compile time Angular does a lot of magic that gets rid of the wrapping and fluff and renders it down to plain HTML anyway.

What I'm saying is that:

```
<Component ngFor="let item of list">
  <ChildComponent>item</Component>
</Component>
```

Will not have a noticeable performance difference to:

```
<ul ngFor="let item of list">
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Meaning that components are definitely the way to go in Angular.

Comment: No he is not looking for static vs dynamic. He is looking for iterating a component in ngFor or populate data OR just by using ngFor, which works best.

Comment: Exactly as @HimanshuSaxena wrote. I have dynamic content, and complex content to show with two generic components and additional operations, and main question is to use child-component with things above or not.

Comment: I changed my answer to suit. Sorry that I misunderstood your question.